# ruby regex inconsistancy

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to convert to roman numerals using gsub with back references, and I've discovered a strange inconsistency.

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-linux]

$ irb
irb(main):001:0>   BASES = {
irb(main):002:1*     1000 => 'M',
irb(main):003:1*     500 => 'D',
irb(main):004:1*     100 => 'C',
irb(main):005:1*     50 => 'L',
irb(main):006:1*     10 => 'X',
irb(main):007:1*     5 => 'V',
irb(main):008:1*     1 => 'I'
irb(main):009:1>   }
=> {1000=>"M", 500=>"D", 100=>"C", 50=>"L", 10=>"X", 5=>"V", 1=>"I"}
irb(main):010:0>   BASE_KEYS = BASES.keys
=> [1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1]
irb(main):011:0> rom = 'IIII'
=> "IIII"
```

above is the setup

below I am trying to identify any character that repeats 4 times,
and replace it with 1 of that character and one the next BASE character.

eg: IIII => IV

```
irb(main):012:0>     rom.gsub(/((.)\2{3})/,
irb(main):013:1*       "#{
irb(main):014:0>         BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):015:2>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
irb(main):016:2>         }.first]
irb(main):017:0>        }
irb(main):018:1"        #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):019:1>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
irb(main):020:1>         }.first}
irb(main):021:1"        #{
irb(main):022:0>         BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{|bk, i|
irb(main):023:2>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
irb(main):024:2>         }.first]
irb(main):025:0>        }
irb(main):026:1"        #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):027:1>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
irb(main):028:1>         }.first}
irb(main):029:1"       "
irb(main):030:1>     )
=> "\n       \n       I\n       1\n      "
```

so i get the wrong answer.. (with debug info for more insights)

```
irb(main):031:0>     rom.gsub(/((.)\2{3})/,
irb(main):032:1*       "#{
irb(main):033:0>         BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):034:2>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
irb(main):035:2>         }.first]
irb(main):036:0>        }
irb(main):037:1"        #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):038:1>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
irb(main):039:1>         }.first}
irb(main):040:1"        #{
irb(main):041:0>         BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{|bk, i|
irb(main):042:2>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
irb(main):043:2>         }.first]
irb(main):044:0>        }
irb(main):045:1"        #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
irb(main):046:1>           BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
irb(main):047:1>         }.first}
irb(main):048:1"       "
irb(main):049:1>     )
=> "I\n       1\n       V\n       5\n      "
irb(main):050:0>
```

admittedly my regex code is barely comprehensible, but why do i get a different result on the second invoke of the same code?

```
irb(main):050:0> rom
=> "IIII"
```

notice rom has not changed...

Comment: If anyone wants to run your code they must first strip out the irb bumph at the beginning of each line. How about doing that for them so they can just cut and paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses `$2` before evaluating the regex. After running it the first time `$2` is set and the code works as intended. Consider using a block instead of a string, because your string is interpolated before the match occurs.

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

This is consistent:

```
rom.gsub(/((.)\2{3})/) { |s|
  "#{
     BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
       BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
     }.first]
    }
    #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
       BASES[BASE_KEYS[i]] == $2
     }.first}
    #{
     BASES[BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{|bk, i|
       BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
     }.first]
    }
    #{BASE_KEYS.select.with_index{ |bk, i|
       BASES[BASE_KEYS[i+1]] == $2
     }.first}
   "
}
# => "I\n    1\n    V\n    5\n   "
```

Comment: thanks. i didnt understand the difference between the priority between the arg and the block. perfect!

Comment: Using long, convoluted interpolations like that makes this code very hard to read. That really needs to be made into a method call.

Comment: @tadman agreed. the block allows me to do this.  code is cleaned now.